# Version History (more...)

Tags: 2010, versioning

In the OOB Version History modal, we are able to see changes that were made to 15 fields for each version. A change to made to any additional fields are trimmed and the text indicator (more...) is added to the list. My question is, is there a way to show all changes to all fields? I know a custom version history form is an option, but I am looking for simpler solutions before I go that route.

A demo of the problem can be seen here. I added an item with 15 custom fields and a Title. The Title and 14 of my fields are shown. Field Text15 is behind the unclickable (more..).

[image: Version History Modal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer in the source of Versions.aspx, the system file used for the Version history modal. In this file at line 330, we can see that the number of changed that can be shown in hard coded at 15. Therefore, there is no way to change this OOB.

It seems my only option is to develop a custom version history page.